# How to port a Func<Hash, string, object> in Java?

Tags: c#, java

How would you port this c# code over to Java?

```
public Hash(object defaultValue)
: this()
{
_defaultValue = defaultValue;
}

public Hash(Func<Hash, string, object> lambda)
: this()
{
_lambda = lambda;
}

public Hash()
{
_nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(Template.NamingConvention.StringComparer);
}
```

Comment: Wow, wtf? Why did this get downvoted so much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing that Java has to delegates is a single method interface using an anonymous inner class. The [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface is somewhat similar to Func.

See these questions:

[Equivalent of C# anonymous methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340231/is-there-an-equivilent-of-c-sharp-anonymous-delegates-in-java)

[Java's equivalents of Func and Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184418/javas-equivalents-of-func-and-action)