# Support for lambda expressions in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In C# when we wanna create methods that can take in lambda expressions as arguments we can use either `Action` or `Func<T>` depending on the situation. The new Java 8 has added support for lambdas but I couldn't find any decent example on how to use that. So assuming that I wanna create a method in Java similar to this C# one:

```
public static Boolean Check (String S, Func<String, Boolean> AnAction) {
     return AnAction(S);
}
```

How exactly could this be written in Java then ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java's equivalents of Func and Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184418/javas-equivalents-of-func-and-action)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html has few nice examples of how to use lambdas, the nicest one there IMHO is Approach 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda expression at runtime is basically an instance of a [functional interface](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/). So, any method that takes a functional interface type as parameter can be passed a lambda expression.

For e.g., Java 8 defines many ready-to-use functional interfaces in [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package. You can use one of them. Or even you can create your own. Equivalent one for your use-case would be [`java.util.function.Function<T, R>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). For boolean return value, you can directly use [`Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) though.

So suppose you've your method defined like this:

```
public static boolean check(String testString, Predicate<String> predicate) {
    return predicate.test(testString);
}
```

And then you can invoke it like this:

```
check("Some String to test predicate on", s -> s.length() > 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your lambda returns a `boolean`, you can use a `Predicate` :

```
public static boolean check (String s, Predicate<String> pred)
{
    return pred.test(s);
}
```

Or you can use a general `Function` :

```
public static Boolean check (String s, Function<String,Boolean> func)
{
    return func.apply(s);
}
```

Comment: I think OP is more interested in how to call the method, at least that's how I interpreted his question since the method it self needs no lambda but the calling.

Comment: @RandRandom `How exactly could this be written in Java then ?` implies OP wants to know how to define methods that accept lambda expressions in Java.