# Equivalent of C# Action() delegate in Java?

Tags: java, c#

C# introduces the concept of delegates, which represent methods that are callable without knowledge of the target object. 
In C# API I have a code:

```
var onReadyAction = new Action(() => OnServerStateChangedSubject.OnNext(ServerState.Connected));
var onTerminatedAction = new Action(() => OnServerStateChangedSubject.OnNext(ServerState.Disconnected));
```

where `OnServerStateChangedSubject.OnNext(ServerState.Connected));`is action witch signalize about server state.
Question: how I can realize this in java?
Code of method:

```
protected TradingClientWithQueue //Client class// KeepConnectAlive()
{
    var onReadyAction = new Action(() => OnServerStateChangedSubject.OnNext(ServerState.Connected));
    var onTerminatedAction = new Action(() => OnServerStateChangedSubject.OnNext(ServerState.Disconnected));

    if (Client == null)
    {
        Client = new TradingClientWithQueue();
        //events 
        Client.OnPacketReceived.Subscribe(OnDataPacketReceivedSubject.OnNext);
        ClientSubscribeOnTerminated(onTerminatedAction);

        Client.OnClientException.Subscribe(OnClientExceptionSubject.OnNext);
        Client.OnClientReady.Subscribe(isReady =>
        {
            AuthenticateClient();
            onReadyAction();
        });

        Client.Connect(Host, Port);
    }
    else
    {
        ClientSubscribeOnTerminated(onTerminatedAction);
        Client.Reconnect(Host, Port);
    }

    return Client;
}
```

Comment: Applicable answers are available in this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184418

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of a delegate is a functional interface.

`Action` is a function which consumes an item and returns void. The most obvious example of an equivalent functional interface would be [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).